# Android - resize image in gallery based on device resolution

Tags: android, image, gallery, resolution

I have an Android app that pulls in images from the Web. 
However when I set:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

the gallery appears to be set to the minimum supported resolution.

Here is the gallery layout definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/GalleryLayout"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="#000000"
              >

<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/gallery"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:spacing="1dip"
         android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the getView class:

```
ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
i.setImageDrawable(drawablesFromUrl[position]);
i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(400, 300));
i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
```

Is there a way to detect the resolution used and then resize the images in the gallery so they stretch to the width of the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

also, you shoudn't use hardcoded pixel values (in `i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(400, 300));`)

use

```
int width = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_width)
int height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_height)
i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(width, height));
```

and in some xml file (under res/values)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <dimen name="image_height">400dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="image_width">300dp</dimen>
</resources>
```