# Resize the images according screen resolution Android

Tags: android, performance

I have a background image in body.
What I want to achieve is that:

1) - Calculate the visitor screen resolution.
2) - based on that resolution I want to resize my background image.

I know get the screen resolution as a

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
width_screen = display.getWidth();
height_screen = display.getHeight();
```

But I don't know how to resize the images according screen resolution of user.

Can anyone help?
Thanks..

Comment: See this answer [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4724183/2332217)

Comment: Guess the link which @oli posted should solve ur prob.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a ImageView in your layout file and set

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

If you want to keep the aspect use:

```
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

If you dont care about the aspect ratio use:

```
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have to write a custom view to do this. Overide onDraw method in it to copy your bitmap as many times as needed.